# Need some examples for the flink-sql streaming process

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Need some examples for the flink-sql streaming process.
Both for the kafka source and database source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good examples in Ververica's training for Flink SQL -- https://github.com/ververica/sql-training. These examples use a Kafka source.

Support for database sources is currently being developed. Flink 1.11 will add support for JDBC (Postgres) catalogs.

Comment: Now If I need to source the data from postgres any workaround ?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Flink 1.11 is coming soon, but I don't know if it will meet your needs. You may also be interested in FLIP-105: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=147427289